# PyQt5 QMYSQL driver building

Tags: mysql, postgresql, qt, pyqt5

I have problem with building the QMYSQL driver on PyQt5. Every solution I find on the internet is focusing on pure Qt (including documentation), not the PyQt5. There is no such files as the ones mentioned in official Qt documentation about driver building, and everything is in wrappers.

Can someone do it or write simple instruction how to implement these methods from Qt documentation in PyQt?

Edit: The driver for QMYSQL are not installed. The error I receive occurs for every driver excluding QSQLITE

Comment: Do you *actually* want to build the plugins, or is your problem that PyQt does not find them?

Comment: `PyQt5` is a Python binding to `QT`, you need a `QT` installation to use it. The `QT` installation is where the plugins(drivers) will be. What OS and version are you on? Add as update to question.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver The PyQt installation (if done through pip) should automatically install the required Qt libraries, as it's a requirement in the wheel.

Comment: @musicamante since there is no indication of how it was installed that is getting ahead of ourselves, especially as there is a sdist out there.

Comment: @musicamante yes, I have to build them, according to internet sources and the qt documentation

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Windows 7. But in the Qt folder there are no files mentioned on the documentation site, even after reinstallation

Comment: @LGusti The plugins should be installed in the Qt distribution path, but if you also built it on your own you probably need to build them too.

Comment: So how are you installing `PyQt5`? Re-installation of what `QT` or `PyQt5`? Please follow directions and add answers as update to your question so folks don't have to go through the comments to get relevant information.